# Cisco L2TP VPNd with GRE over IPsec tunnel

Tags: cisco, tunnel, l2tp

I have a GRE over IPsec tunnel between router 1 and router 2.

The routing between the 2 routers is EIGRP.

I have access to the CLI and I can ping all subnets.

I try to create VPNd L2TP

I create it, and from the CLI I can ping all subnets, but from my PC I cannot ping any IP address from Tunnel2354.

```
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login telnet local
aaa authentication ppp default local
aaa authorization network default local
aaa session-id common
ip subnet-zero
ip cef
!
!
!
!
ip ips po max-events 100
vpdn enable
!
vpdn-group CDATA
! Default L2TP VPDN group
! Default PPTP VPDN group
accept-dialin
protocol any
virtual-template 6
no l2tp tunnel authentication
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 56
encr aes
authentication pre-share
crypto isakmp key rMVvTRvm2Hw7rUxCdIGQAOsiwfmXv1/i address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
no crypto isakmp ccm
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set device1 esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto ipsec profile deviceProfile1
set transform-set device1
!
!
!
!
!
interface Tunnel2354
ip address 10.54.65.1 255.255.255.0
tunnel source FastEthernet0/0
tunnel destination xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
tunnel protection ipsec profile deviceProfile1
!
interface Loopback2
ip address 10.54.63.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 255.255.255.252
ip nat outside
ip virtual-reassembly
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 255.255.255.248 secondary
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface Virtual-Template6
ip unnumbered Tunnel2354
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly
ip mroute-cache
peer default ip address pool vpn
no keepalive
ppp authentication ms-chap-v2
!
router eigrp 1
network 10.54.65.0 0.0.0.255
auto-summary
!
ip local pool vpn 10.14.0.109 10.14.0.120
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
!
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
```

Comment: You need to add a sanitized config for R2 and also give us an example of what you’re attempting to ping (give specific IP addresses).